# Java Azure ServiceBusService listQueues() capped at 100 queues?

Tags: java, azure, queue, servicebus

I'm using the Azure SDK in Eclipse, and I'm attempting to retrieve a list of all the queues associated with a service bus.  I'm able to properly connect to the service bus, but when I call listQueues it only returns the first 100 queues (there's about 130)

```
ListQueuesOptions options = new ListQueuesOptions();

    options.setTop(200);
    options.setSkip(0);

    System.out.println(options.getTop());

    ListQueuesResult queuesResult = serviceBusContract.listQueues(options);
    List<QueueInfo> list = queuesResult.getItems();

    for (QueueInfo info : list)
    {
        System.out.println("Queue name: " + info.getPath());
    }
```

It does seem like ListQueuesOptions is supposed to modify the way queues are retrieved, and it does.  Setting top to 20 and skip to 0 gives the first 20, setting top to 40 and skip to 20 the second 20, and so on.  But if I run the above code I still only print 100 queues.  Is it limited at 100 for some reason?

I am aware that I can probably just keep calling listQueues in iterations of 100 and count to see if I've hit 100, and then run it again, but this is a really strange issue so I thought I'd ask since the documentation isn't very clear on this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The maximum you can set for top is 100. You need ask for batched of 100 each time. Use skip to get the next batch.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried firing up something like fiddler or wireshark to inspect the response to the request? I've checked the API for List Queues (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh780759.aspx) and don't see any paging behavior, so i can't help but surmise that its returning the entire list (in an AtomPub format according to the doc) and the the result is then parsed by the java SDK.

So is it possible this is a bug in the SDK you're using?